# Sum of two independent Martingale also martingale : solution from Ross

Tags: probability-theory, expectation, martingales, conditional-expectation

Hi I am working on problem 6.8 from Sheldon Ross's Stochastic Processes book.
[image]

The given solution at the back of the book goes like: 
[image]

Here I am confused on the red boxed part. How the assumption of X and Y's independency allows to go from $E[X_n|X_i + Y_i, i = 1,..,n-1]$ to $E[X_n|X_i, i = 1,..,n-1]$ in the inner expectation? I am having hard time to "prove" it systematically using properties of expectation.

For the problem, I am thinking my solution more like this:

$$E[X_n|X_i + Y_i, i = 1,..,n-1]$$
$$ = E[E[X_n|X_i + Y_i, i = 1,..,n-1]|Y_1,..., Y_{n-1}]$$
$$ = E[E[X_n|X_i, i = 1,..,n-1]|Y_1,..., Y_{n-1}]$$ 
$$ = E[X_{n-1}|Y_1,..., Y_{n-1}]$$
$$ = X_{n-1}$$

Could someone help me understand how to logically come to the rectangular boxed portion of the official solution?

Comment: Hint: $$E(X_n\mid X_i+Y_i,X_i,1\leqslant i\leqslant n-1)=E(X_n\mid X_i,Y_i,1\leqslant i\leqslant n-1)=E(X_n\mid X_i,1\leqslant i\leqslant n-1)$$

Answer (score 1):

First of all, note that $\mathbb{E}[Z|X+Y,X]=\mathbb{E}[Z|X,Y]$, since $\sigma(X,Y) = \sigma(X+Y,X)$, which is easy to check (using the minimal property of sigma algebra generated by a collection of maps):

- $X$ and $X+Y$ are both $\sigma(X,Y)$-measurable $\Rightarrow$ $\sigma(X,X+Y)\subseteq\sigma(X,Y)$
- $X$ and $Y=(X+Y)-X$ are both $\sigma(X+Y,X)$-measurable $\Rightarrow$ $\sigma(X,Y)\subseteq\sigma(X+Y,X)$

This allows us to write
$$\mathbb{E}[X_n|X_i+Y_i, X_i, i=1,...,n-1] = \mathbb{E}[X_n|X_i, Y_i, i=1,...,n-1]$$
which by independence (see for example property 9.7-(k) of [Williams](http://static.stevereads.com/papers_to_read/probability_with_martingales_williams_.pdf)) is equal to
$$\mathbb{E}[X_n|X_i, i=1,...,n-1]$$

Then by martingale property of $X_n$ this inner conditional expectation is equal to $X_{n-1}$.